# How to parse .ics file in Java?

Tags: java

I need to parse outlook calendar file(.ics).

How to parse it using Java?

Is there any API available to parse the calendar file?

Answer (score 4):

try iCal4J: http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page